# Image magick create img with specific pixel width

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagick

I am creating this image:

[image]

using this command:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke lime -draw "line 105,400 205,400" -stroke blue -draw "line 105,405 205,405" -stroke blue -strokewidth 2 -draw "rectangle 140,150 260,230 " -draw "rectangle 320,150 440,230 " -draw "rectangle 500,150 620,230 " -draw "rectangle 140,300 260,380 " -draw "rectangle 320,300 440,380 " -draw "rectangle 500,300 620,380 " test.png
```

but my image shall look like this:

[image]

each rectangle shall have a width of 180px and a height of 120px, and the green/blue line shall have a width of 170px and a height of 10px how do I specify this?

I tried rostok's suggestion and it created me this image, which is not 100% correct:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
magick convert \
-size 720x480 xc:black \
-strokewidth 4 \
-stroke lime \
-draw "line 103,467 273,467" \
-stroke #0030ff \
-draw "line 103,471 273,471" \
-strokewidth 9 \
-draw "path 'M 108,159 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'" \
-draw "path 'M 290,159 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'" \
-draw "path 'M 472,159 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'" \
-draw "path 'M 108,288 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'" \
-draw "path 'M 290,288 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'" \
-draw "path 'M 472,288 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'" \
output.png
```

Your rects have different stroke width in horizontal and vertical sides however I assumed you wanted same stroke everywhere.

Comment: It is not working a 100% I posted the image which your command does create you may have a look at it.

Comment: This is really strange. I tried this code with: Linux, ImageMagick 6.3.7 11/17/10 Q16, Win ImageMagick 6.7.9-8 2012-09-22 Q8 and even Win ImageMagick 7.0.2-5 Q16 x64 and all worked good. What version are you using?

Comment: @rostock I am using version: ImageMagick 7.0.2-0 Q16 x64 2016-06-12

Comment: yep it's really strange it draws all lines correctly, apart from the bottom lines

Comment: Update IM. I tried with your version and can confirm it isn't working properly.

Comment: @rostock did you find another hint yet :)

Comment: My only suggestion is to update IM to latest stable version or revert to v6.

Comment: Ok after downgrading my version to 6.9.3-7 it did worked thanks alot

Comment: I have just one more question could you explain what each "coordinate" does (whre it belongs to)

Comment: Full specs are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths. Note that upper and lowercase letters do matter as they can be absolute position coordinates (upper) or relative (lower). Obviously I chose lower for most cases in order to cut and paste remaining lines.

Comment: do you know a way to make it fully transparent (instead of the black background) I did this xc:transparent and the black background inside of the rectangles are still blacks where as the rest is transparent

Comment: add '-fill none' before first draw path

Comment: is it possible to calculate how big the area shall be inside of the rectangle for instance 220x145 px ?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Basically I want the areas which the rectangles surround (black area inside of the rectangles) have a size of 220x145px, how do I have to change the command if I want to achieve this?

Comment: Thus is there a way to center this?

Comment: You should read the specs at mozilla's site. Regardless, the path syntax is quite obvious. For example in `-draw "path 'M 472,288 h 171 v 111 h -171 v -115 Z'"` M sets the starting point, h draws line horizontally, v vertically. Adjust accordingly if you want to have rectangle with different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks I understood everything except for that last -115 Z, so far as I understand it goes back to the starting point but why do you have that value -115? The docs stated out this **The path will move to point (10,10) and then move horizontally 80 points to the right, then 80 points down, then 80 points to the left, and then back to the start.**

Comment: The extra 4 pixels are to make sure rect is fully rectangular. Without it starting corner would be chipped. Probably there are some other, better ways to draw such rectangles. I wanted to cut&paste as much as possible and minimize need to enter different parameters.